# How do I revert a trunk merge from a tag

Tags: linux, svn

After my last release, I tagged my trunk with a

```
svn copy https://svn.abc.com/svn/project/trunk https://svn.abc.com/svn/project/tags/release_20120722 -m "Tagging the release of feature"
```

If I've merged something to the trunk that I don't want, and I need to revert to this tag, what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create revert diff like this `svn diff https://svn.abc.com/svn/project/trunk https://svn.abc.com/svn/project/tags/release_20120722 > tmp.diff` and patch your trunk with that `patch -p0 -i tmp.diff`.

Comment: how would go about doing the patch?